# JavaMail IMAP concept that related to download data and memory size

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am now using android javamail to implement sync IMAP messages. I have memory and performance concerned. So i would like to get more clear concept for this when using the java mail api.

When getting the inbox folder from the store, I cast it to IMAP Folder. I don't need to use pop3(totally ignore pop3).

```
IMAPFolder inbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX")
```

1. I would like to know Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
   Is this just create the inbox message count array?
2. I saw there is some explanation for POP3. POP3 needs to download all messages. So for the effective download, the application can use FetchProfile to add which part of info would like to download. 
   Is this the same in IMAPMessage, getFrom(), getSubject()??
   for example :

   `IMAPMessage msg = (IMAPMessage) messages[i];`

   `Log.i(TAG, "UID": + inbox.getUID(msg));`

   `Log.i(TAG, "SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());`

   In my sample code, i didn't use FetchProfile, i just use message array to get the info what i want? but i do like to know how it handle in javamail library?
3. When searching with string term search and override the match() to find. it loop over every message to find match messages array.

   Message[] message = inbox.search(new SearchTerm() { xxxx })

   Are all the IMAP messages are downloaded from the server? 
   If we need to do several search term, then will the downloaded messages cache for the next search? 
   How to do more effective search? for example if need to search messageId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it creates Message objects to represent each message in the folder.
2. Using Folder.fetch with a FetchProfile will cause it to prefetch the requested data and store it in the corresponding Message objects.  Without the prefetch, the data is fetched on demand, one message at a time.
3. The built-in search terms are translated to IMAP search commands, which execute on the server.  If you create your own search term, e.g., by subclassing an existing one, the message data needs to be downloaded to the client to perform the search there.  There's already a [standard Message-ID search term](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/MessageIDTerm.html).